# Amazon web service- API Gate way - Custom authorizer using lambda function issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a scenario where the caller of my services is going to pass a JWT (JSON web token), and I want to pass that value to a custom authorizer that uses lambda function in order to decrypt it and return a policy to that caller where the policy can be allow that user or deny it. in addtion of adding a header value after the lambda completes the JWT decryption.

for Example:

1. The caller (end user) call a service serviceX(POST/Get).
2. call reaches AWS API GateWay
3. Service is marked with authorised method which is custom authorizer
4. Custom Authorizer calls lambda function
5. Lambda function decrypt the JWT
6. Lambda function adds a new header/modify an existing one
7. end service (serviceX) receives the request

I have implemented all the above example except number 6, I can't add a new header value from lambda or modify an existing one.

I have searched a lot and I can't find a way to do so.

any further documentation or snippets from AWS about this issue I will provide it by request -if needed-.

Comment: What are you using as an integration? HTTP, Lambda, another AWS service?

Comment: I am using HTTP

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set a header from the custom authorizer. You can however return a context map of values that you can use in the serviceX function.

So the custom authorizer returns the policy together with a context:

```
{
    "principalId": "yyyyyyyy",
    "policyDocument": {
        ... blah blah ...
    },
    "context": {
        "customvalue": "response-from-number-6"
    }
}
```

Then you can access it in the serviceX function in the the following attribute:

```
$context.authorizer.customvalue
```

Does that solve your number 6 of returning a value from the custom authorizer?

Comment: are you referring to use the customvalue in the serviceX payload/body ? and I have used this senior to set the customvalue in the serviceX payload, but i need to use this customvalue to add it in the request header. do you have any ideas how to implement this ?

Comment: You can use the same syntax `$context.authorizer.customvalue` to set the value for a request header to serviceX